# jasper work fine in netbeans but it throw exception

Tags: java, netbeans, jasper-reports

My code on button click event is this:

```
 private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        try {
            Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:Sample");
           HashMap hm=new HashMap();
           JasperReport jre;
           jre=JasperCompileManager.compileReport("D:\\test java\\JavaApplication2\\report2.jasper");
                JasperPrint jr = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jre, hm, con);
                JasperExportManager.exportReportToHtmlFile(jr, "D:\\test java\\JavaApplication2\\report2.html" );  
           JasperViewer.viewReport(jr,false);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
        catch(SQLException se)
        {
            System.out.println(se.getMessage());
        }
         catch (JRException ex) {
                System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
            }
    }
```

Exception in netbeans

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/digester/Digester
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager.compileReport(JasperCompileManager.java:146)
        at pkg.NewJFrame.jButton1ActionPerformed(NewJFrame.java:83)
        at pkg.NewJFrame.access$000(NewJFrame.java:30)
        at pkg.NewJFrame$1.actionPerformed(NewJFrame.java:53)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1995)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2318)
        at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:387)
        at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:242)
        at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:236)
        at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6038)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3260)
        at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:5803)
        at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2058)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4410)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2116)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4240)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4322)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:3986)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:3916)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2102)
        at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2429)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4240)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:599)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:273)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:183)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:173)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:168)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:160)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:121)
```

Answer (score 1):

you are probably missing a jasper report dependency.

seems like you did not add the apache commons-digester.jar into the classpath.

you will also need:
commons-beanutils
commons-collections
commons-logging