# retrieving data from jasper file

Tags: java, jasper-reports

Hi I am very new to jasper reports. Just have a requirement where i need to retrieve the info from a .jasper file. I am using the below code for that.

But issue is compileReport does not take up the file i have in my local machine and i get a error like

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/digester/Digester
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager.compileReport(JasperCompileManager.java:150)
>       at jasper.test(jasper.java:28)
>       at jasper.main(jasper.java:40)

I am not sure what is wrong.Is it not able to get my .jasper file? which class is missing?
I am absolutely clueless.

## My code is:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import dori.jasper.engine.JRException;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRDataSource;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperPrint;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperReport;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperExportManager;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource;
import net.sf.jasperreports.view.JasperViewer;


public class jasper  {

    public static void test() throws FileNotFoundException, net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException{

    JasperReport report = JasperCompileManager.compileReport("C:\\Users\\Mandakini\\Downloads\\testReport.jasper");

    JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(report, new HashMap<String, String>());
    // export it!
    //File pdf = File.createTempFile("output.", ".pdf");

    OutputStream output= new FileOutputStream(new File("F:/catalog.pdf"));
    JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfStream(print,output);

    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws FileNotFoundException, net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException{
        test();
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: You're missing whatever jar contains class `org/apache/commons/digester/Digester`  from your classpath.

Comment: I added all jars. The error i am getting now is - Exception in thread "main" net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.io.MalformedByteSequenceException: Invalid byte 1 of 1-byte UTF-8 sequence. what needs to be done, i am confused searching a solution for ths, what i am giving as a parameter to compileReport is the .jasper file(the report). Is there anything wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jasper work fine in netbeans but it throw exception](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5839077/jasper-work-fine-in-netbeans-but-it-throw-exception)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` or `ClassNotFoundException` should almost always tell you that the class it references is missing from your classpath. In this case, it's `org.apache.commons.digester.Digester`.  You can download the jar containing this class [here](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-digester/download_digester.cgi).

To produce a report, do something like:

```
JasperReport jasperReport = (JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObjectFromFile(yourJasperFilePath);

Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<>();
// set your parameters

Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
Connection con = ...; // possibly get a connection

byte[] report = JasperRunManager.runReportToPdf(jasperReport, parameters, con); // pass the report, the report parameters, and a connection 
// this will fill the byte[] with the produced report

FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(somePath);
out.write(report);
out.close();
```

As to what kind of report it generates, I'm not sure how you set that. That info might be in the `.jasper` or `.jrxml` file.

Comment: Hi Sotirios Delimanolis, I added all jars. The error i am getting now is -  Exception in thread "main" net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.io.MalformedByteSequenceException: Invalid byte 1 of 1-byte UTF-8 sequence.
what needs to be done, i am confused searching a solution for ths, what i am giving as a parameter to compileReport is the .jasper file(the report). Is there anything wrong?

Comment: @nisha A `.jasper` file is already compiled (like a java `.class` file). I think what you want is the `jrxml` file.

Comment: You mean, if i want to retrieve the information from a .jasper file, i need to get the jrxml file? I can get the jrxml by decompiling .jasper file. Is this what you mean? i took a program that does so, but i got again "Exception in thread "main" net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRuntimeException: Unknown hyperlink target 0"    The code i>  sourcePath = "C\:ort.jasper";
        destinationPath = "F:/catalog.jrxml";
        JasperReport report = (JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObject(sourcePath);
        JRXmlWriter.writeReport(report, destinationPath, "UTF-8");

Comment: @ Sotirios Delimanolis , I have a .jasper file.I want to get the data inside the .jasper file in a readable xml or pdf file.

Comment: @nisha That's where the confusion is. You want to produce a report from the `.jasper` file? I've added an example of how you would do that.

Comment: @ Sotirios Delimanolis - why do i need a connection?I replaced   JasperReport jasperReport = (JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObjectFromLocation("C:\\Users\\Mandakini\\Downloads\\testReport.jasper");
from your code. Everything else is kept same, since i just need the pdf from jasper which is in my local machine. I still get same exception-"Exception in thread "main" net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRuntimeException: Unknown hyperlink target 0"

Comment: I dont want to use any tool for this. Just through java program how i can acieve this?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29746/discussion-between-nisha-and-sotirios-delimanolis)